# terminal won't open npm binary even if it's right there

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed a global npm package using `sudo npm install mtemplate -g`. The `mtemplate` package appears in my `/usr/local/bin` directory. It shows up when I type `ls` in the terminal in that directory. I can see it in finder.

**BUT** when I type `mtemplate` or `/usr/local/bin/mtemplate` in the terminal (or any variation thereof) I get

`No such file or directory`

According to the docs it should be possible to run `mtemplate` from the terminal. Why isn't it found even when it's right there?

Comment: `chmod +x ./mtemplate`?

Comment: I figured it out... the `mtemplate` linked to a .js file that had windows Line Endings, and apparently node on mac won't execute those! After converting the .js file to Unix it works...

Comment: Oh yeah, I've had that problem before. Good catch. Maybe submit an issue on the package for that. Also post a self-answer and I'll upvote you

Answer (score 0):

After much head-scratching I figured it out myself... the `mtemplate` in `usr/local` links to a `mtemplate.js` file in `node_modules`. That .js file had windows Line Endings, and apparently node on mac won't execute those!

After converting the Line Endings to Unix it works...